# Running multiple docker-compose overrides at once

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a `docker-compose.yml` file which is setup for two environments, `dev` and `prod`:

**docker-compose.yml**

Contains shared configuration for both environments

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    homeassistant:
        restart: unless-stopped
        privileged: true
        network_mode: host
```

**docker-compose.dev.yml**

Contains configuration for development environment

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    homeassistant:
        image: registry.gitlab.com/addisonlynch/homeassistant/hass:dev
        container_name: hass-dev
```

**docker-compose.prod.yml**

Contains configuration for production environment

```
version: '3.1'
services:
    homeassistant:
        image: registry.gitlab.com/addisonlynch/homeassistant/hass:prod
        container_name: hass-prod
```

I can run the dev environment as follows:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

and the prod environment:

```sh
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml up
```

Both of the environments run flawlessly, however I can only have one running at the same time. If I try to spin up prod while dev is running (on the same host), the dev containers will exit and prod containers will start (effectively replacing them). **How do I run both environments at the same time?**

Comment: Are these the exact docker compose files? Maybe you have some similar ports ors something else is overlapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do `docker-compose --help` you'll see:

```
 -p, --project-name NAME     Specify an alternate project name
                              (default: directory name)
```

What this means is that, by default, when you do `docker-compose up`, Compose manages your services as part of a project which is named after directory name in which `docker-compose.yml` file is. Since your dev & prod compose files are in the same directory and have the same service names, there's no way for Compose to distinguish one from the other.

With that in mind, in order to have both dev & prod environment running at the same time, you need to specify project name via `-p` or `--project-name` flag like:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml -p dev_env up
```

Another option is to use [`COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) environment variable like:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=dev_env docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.dev.yml up
```

---

Potential problem in your case could be `host` network mode, if both dev & prod use the same ports. In that case, the one you start second won't be able to start.

Answer (score 1):

As it is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41835834/2596409) you can use `-p` option to set the project name of the containers and run it multiple times with different prefix names for containers.

`docker-compose -p dev`

`docker-compose -p prod`