# docker-compose collapse after running another instance of docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, gitlab-ci

I have a docker-compose.yml that have been written for the option to run parallel in CI from different locations.
But when I'm trying to run `docker-compose up` for the second time the containers of the first docker-compose's containers are shutting.

```
version: '3.7'

x-default-values: &default-values
  image: some_image:${CI_JOB_ID}
  env_file:
    - env_file.txt
  init: true
  volumes:
    - "first_vol:/some/path"
    - "second_vol:/some/path2"

x-rest-default-values: &rest-default-values
  image: some_image:${CI_JOB_ID}
  volumes:
    - "first_vol:/some/path"
  init: true

volumes:
  first_vol:
    name: ${CI_JOB_ID_first_vol
  second_vol:
    name: ${CI_JOB_ID}_second_vol
    external: true

networks:
  default:
    name: ${CI_JOB_ID}_net
    external: true

services:
  some_service:
    container_name: ${CI_JOB_ID}_some_service
    command: "some command"
    <<: *default-values
    env_file:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/env_file.txt
  some_rest_service:
    container_name: ${CI_JOB_ID}_some_rest_service
    command: "some rest command"
    <<: *rest-default-values
  localstack:
    container_name: ${CI_JOB_ID}_localstack
    image: localstack:${CI_JOB_ID}
    env_file:
    - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/env_file.txt
    environment:
    - EDGE_PORT=4566
    - SERVICES=sqs,sns,s3
```

My docker-compose.yml look like this with more services but with pretty much same templates.
Trying to understand what I'm missing that causing the docker-compose collapse when running more than one instance (those instances are running from different location: CI_PROJECT_DIR and with other CI_JOB_ID).

I can reproduce it locally and "debug" it, but I'm not sure what should I look for (the external volume is exist and also the network and the flow is fine when running one instance). So I would like to get an advise how to investigate it further.

I tried to run multiple instances of docker-compose in parallel. Expected to work but to container of the first instance are shutting down after the second instance is up.

Comment: Are all of the projects using the same Compose project name?  (Do they run from the same directory; do use the `docker-compose -p` option or `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable?)  For example, [How do I run the same docker-compose.yml several times on same docker daemon with different names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831582/how-do-i-run-the-same-docker-compose-yml-several-times-on-same-docker-daemon-wit)

Comment: Yes, seems that -p is solving the issue.
Thanks a lot