# Can I rename the original image in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-container, docker-image

### My Configuration

My docker-compose.yml looks like this with some config for backend etc..., but I need some changes for `db` service.

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  db:
    container_name: db-${STAGE:-dev}
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env.${STAGE:-dev}
```

I don't want to have multiple docker-compose.yml files, so...

### What do I want?

I want to run this docker-compose.yml twice, the first time with STAGE=prod and the second time with STAGE=dev. I need to use different .env files (.env.dev, .env.prod), because of once the `db` service is built, the image name is `postgres:14.0-alpine` and it also builds with only one of the .env.${STAGE} files, so it will only work with `development` or `production`, due to different passwords etc....

I want to build **2 different images** for postgres db (e.g. db-dev and db-prod) that will use .env.dev for db-dev and .env.prod for db-prod.

The reason I want to do this is that I would like to deploy both a development and a production server on one VPS, I'm not sure if this is a good idea, so can you give me some recommendations on this as well please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most important statement in the question is this:

> I want to run this docker-compose.yml twice

Compose has the notion of a [project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/envvars/#compose_project_name).  This affects the names of most things Compose generates.  These include the containers themselves; the project name is included not just in the default project name but also in labels attached to the containers.  A common related problem here is that running `STAGE=qa docker-compose up -d` will delete the `STAGE=dev` containers; for example, [How do I run the same docker-compose.yml several times on same docker daemon with different names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41831582/how-do-i-run-the-same-docker-compose-yml-several-times-on-same-docker-daemon-wit)

The first important thing you can do is start the two Compose instances with different project names.  You can do this with a `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` environment variable or a `docker-compose -p` option.  Whichever you use, you need to make sure it's available for all `docker-compose` invocations.

```bash
STAGE=dev
docker-compose -p "$STAGE" up -d
docker-compose -p "$STAGE" ps
```

The project name also gets included in the names of other generated objects.  This especially includes volumes.  If your top-level `volumes:` block is just a minimal

```yaml
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    # empty
```

then the underlying Docker volume will be named after the project name.

The important thing that's happening in your setup, I think, is that you're reusing the existing *volume* between the "dev" and "prod" environments.  You're using the same *image* as well, but that's normal – you're not recompiling the PostgreSQL server for different environments.  Setting the Compose project name will work around this and give you a different volume for each environment.

In your Compose setup you can also use `$COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` explicitly.  You might be able to save a step by letting Compose choose the names of all of the objects, and using the project name directly in the one place you need it (the `env_file:` name).

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres:14.0-alpine
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    env_file:
      - .env.${COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME}
volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

```bash
# without setting $STAGE
docker-compose -p dev up -d
```